# When is the Struts Convention Plug-in Applied?

Tags: struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

I’m trying to understand how the Convention plugin determines when to do URL interpretation. In some [REST Plug-in examples](https://github.com/nitinsurana/Struts2-Examples/tree/master/Struts2RestConvention) I see `PrefixBasedActionMapper` [configured with `”/rest:rest,:struts”`](https://github.com/nitinsurana/Struts2-Examples/blob/master/Struts2RestConvention/src/main/resources/struts.xml) and it seems that Convention is only applied to the `rest` mapper and not the `DefaultActionMapper`. Is this correct? Either way, under what conditions does the Convention plugin kick in for requests?

I’ve been googling like a mad-man these last two days and can’t seem to find any explanation. Inspecting the plugin source didn't give any insights either.

Comment: Not sure what are you asking. If you have convention plugin in your classpath then it is working (if you haven't disabled it somehow).

Comment: What do you mean by Convention? You can mix the rest convention and convention plugin convention as well as defined by the example.

Answer (score 1):

They are different. `Convention Plugin` is not about URL/action mapping. It just search java classes and create action configs from them.

However, you can tell the plugin to search specific root packages using the property `struts.convention.action.packages`. e.g.

```
<constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="com.mycompany.myactions.myconvention.*"/>
```